# How to count total no of records based on value using codiegniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
  id | name | status

   1 |  name | yes

   2 |  name | no 

   3 |  name | yes
```

How i can count total status with value yes and with value no using active records ? Like count is : **yes = 2** , **no = 1**

This is what i have tried so far

```
$this->db->select('count(status));
//$this->db->select('count(where status == 'yes')); // not working
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `where` method of CI to add where condition.change your query like below:

```
$this->db->select('count(status)');
$this->db->where('status','yes'); // apply where
$query = $this->db->get();
```

To get all status count, use group by clause

```
$this->db->select('status,count(status)');
$this->db->group_by('status'); // apply group by
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank for the answer,but for this i need two queries,one for status yes and for status no.Can we do with single query ? @B.Desai

Comment: Use group by for it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('yourtablename');
        $this->db->where("(status = 'yes' AND id = '2' )", NULL, FALSE);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: So i need two queries to fetch count for both the status ? @N. francis

Comment: Could you breakdown what you want to achieve?

Comment: count total status "Yes" and "No" in one query

Comment: You could do that in your view, for example, <?php $total = $first_query + $second_query echo $total; ?> There are different ways to achieve a goal, you could use other methods. Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

Simply group by then count.

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT
            status,
            count(*) as count
        FROM
            TABLENAME
        GROUP BY
            status
    ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
```